# How to access files on host with subdomain

Tags: php, url, server, cpanel, host

I have an image for example at `example.com/assets/images/logo.png` and I have a subdomain called test.
I want to access the logo.png file from `test.example.com/assets/images/logo.png` but I get a 404 error. How can I access my files from a subdomain?

Comment: Assuming that the sub-domain points to the same server, you need to add an alias to the virutalhost for the second domain.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: @AlexBarker thanks for your answer, can you explain a little more on how I can do it?

Comment: If you post your web server's virtual host config I will show you what to edit.